# Entering UK two times in 12 months

Tags: united-kingdom, driving

Basically I have got foreign car UK Driving License. Can I enter UK two times in 12 months. I mean like I enter country and I stay here for couple months and I leave  and come back again. Example - I have stayed here 4 months, then I have decided to leave and come back again and stay 6 months. Is it allowed to do like that with foreign car If I have got insurance and all documents from foreign country?

Answer (score 2):

You may only use a foreign registered car in the UK for up to 6 months in any 12 month period so it depends how long you will be living outside the UK. https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports

Comment: Depending on how they count, and on how much time elapses between the visits, it might be okay.

Comment: @phoog good point, the question didn't specify how long they were going to be away. I'll edit the answer. Also, I have reason to believe enforcement is nonexistent.